# Is a − path followed by a − path is a − path.

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

Can I say a − path followed by a − path is a − path.

Because if there is a path from − followed by − I believe there should be a − path.

I don't know how to prove it.

EDIT:
A − path is a path between vertex  and  vertex. and − path is a path between vertex  and  vertex

A walk is a sequence of vertices and edges of a graph i.e. if we traverse a graph, then we get a walk.

A path is a walk with no repeated vertex. This directly implies that no edges will ever be repeated

Comment: It's hard to address your question without knowing exactly how you define a "$u$-$v$ path". I suggest that you edit your question to provide the definition.

Comment: When you write "a $u-v$ path", do you mean a path from some point $u$ to some other point $v$, or are you implying some sort of subtraction of $v$ from $u$? Your question does not make it clear. If it's the first meaning, then the answer by @MPW below answers you quite well. If it's the second, then we definitely need more details.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I have made an edit to the question

Comment: Hey, i just noticed that you have the tag 'graph theory' on your post. Not everybody looks at the tags, so you might want to include the phrase "in a (directed) graph" in the body of your question. Me, I don't even know what formal definition of a path in a graph people use in graph theory.

Comment: You also need to define *path*.  If the definition prohibits repeated vertices, then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that the $vw$ path contains the vertex $u$, the concatenation of $uv$ and $vw$ is not a path, but a walk. To be a path, you have to make sure it does not contains two identical vertices.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $f,g:[0,1]\to X$ and $f(1)=g(0)$, then $h:[0,1]\to X$ and $h(0)=f(0)$ and $h(1)=g(1)$, where
$$h(t) =
\begin{cases}
f(2t),& 0\leq t <\tfrac12\\
g(2t-1),& \tfrac12 \leq t \leq 1
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Probably not the intended definition in the case of graph theory.

Comment: @MishaLavrov : Indeed. I should have noticed the tags.

Comment: I didn't notice the tags either, and thought this was an excellent answer  :-(